# Display the hash values in angular2

Tags: angular

I want to display the values of hashes in angular2. I am getting response in hash format:

```
[{"1":"7"},{"2":"6"},{"3":"8"},{"4":"1"}]
```

"1" is user_id and "7" is the count of its posts. I need to display it in users index page in table.

```
User_Id  Posts
 1        7
 2        6
```

Could anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this

```
data:any = [{"1":"7"},{"5":"6"},{"3":"8"},{"4":"1"}];
ngOnInit(){
this.data =  this.data.map( i => {
 //we need to create a new array to store the new data.
  let newItem = [];
//gets the property name. So this is 1,5,3,4
   const propertyName = Object.keys(i)[0];
      newItem[0]= propertyName;
//gets the value. So this is 7,6,8,1
      newItem[1] = i[propertyName] ;
      return newItem;
})
}
```

Check the demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rispse?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

I'm not that good in javascript and there must be a better way to do this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting this in browser console.ERROR TypeError: this.data.map is not a function.

Comment: So how did you apply the `this.data.map` in your code?  Isn't it the `users_post`? You should do somehting like `users_post.map`

Comment: yes I have used data like this: 
data: any= JSON.stringify(this.users_post); then I have mapped like you have posted.

Comment: you don't need to use the JSON.stringify!

Comment: remove the `json.stringify` and try `this.users_post.map(...)`

Comment: Thanks @brijmcq I got the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
in component you will use the response to parse like this
response = JSON.stringify(obj);




 <table class="table table-inverse">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>User_Id</th>
          <th>Posts</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let resonse of responseDto;">
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>response['User_Id']</td>
        </tr>
        <tr*ngFor="let resonse of responseDto;">
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>response['Posts']</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: response = JSON.stringify(this.users_post);
I am getting Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Post[]'.

Comment: check the type of both. you can learn more about stringify here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can split user_id and post into 2 different arrays and populate your table using these arrays. Here userIdArray will give you [1,2,3,4] and postsArray will give you [7,6,8,1].

```
var userIdArray = [];
var postsArray = [];
array.forEach(function(userObject) {
    //userObject = {"1":"7"} or {"2":"6"} etc...
    userIdArray.push(Object.keys(userObject)[0]);
    postsArray.push(userObject[userIdArray[array.indexOf(userObject)]]);
});
```

I've not tested shashi's answer would like to know if that one works, as that seems more feasible to me, in terms of using loops.